# An inequality on the product of primes

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

> Let $p_n$ denote the $n$-th prime ($p_1=2$)
>
> Let $\pi(n)$ be the numbers of primes less or equal to $n$.
>
> Prove that $$n^{\pi(2n)-\pi(n)}\leq \prod_{n+1\leq p_k\leq 2n}p_k\leq \binom{2n}{n}$$

I've seen this problem in Makarov's book *Selected problems in real analysis*.

He doesn't provide any hints, so it shouldn't be difficult, with respect to his higher standard of difficulty ;)

**EDIT** I corrected the statement to be proved. @Restrest's answer to the previous flawed version of the question can be adapted to prove the left bound. I still can't prove the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right inequality can be proven as follows:

$ 2n\choose n $ is an integer which is divisible by all primes $ n<p \leq 2n $. Therefore, $ 2n\choose n $ divided by the product of primes is a positive integer, proving the claim.

Answer (score 1):

The left inequality is simple:

$\pi(2n)-\pi(n) \le n$ and $p_k \ge n$ for every $k\ge n+1$. This provides required inequality.

And the right one looks wrong. Check it for $n = 3$, for example.

Comment: Ah, I'm quite embarassed I missed that. thanks

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM, check please right inequality for n=3, as it provides 77*13 <= 20

Comment: The inequality must be valid for larger $n$ I guess. I don't have my copy of the book atm, so I'll need to check.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM, it looks wrong for all n. $p_n >= 2n$ and the central expression is even bigger than (2n)!/n!

Comment: I edited the question. Your proof adapts readily.